# Why am i getting an infinite list with stack overflow?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

Im making an bungalow reservation system but i cant get a list with an many to many relationship i keep getting an infinite list with stackoverflow error.
This worked find but happens when i added the many to many relationship.

Attraction Entity this contains a many to many relationship with
the visit entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attraction")
public class Attraction {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 @Column(name = "historical")
 private Boolean historical;

 @Column(name = "religious")
 private Boolean religious;

 @Column(name = "beaches")
 private Boolean beaches;

 @Column(name = "animal_sanc")
 private Boolean animalSanc;

 @Column(name = "hiking")
 private Boolean hiking;

 @Column(name = "forest")
 private Boolean forest;

 @Column(name = "parks")
 private Boolean parks;

 @Column(name = "lakes")
 private Boolean lakes;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "bungalow_id")
 private Bungalow bungalow;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
 @JoinTable(
        name = "visit_has_attraction",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attraction_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "visit_id")
 )
 private List<Visit> visitList;
 //Constructer, Getters and Setters
}
```

Visit entity
This is the other end of the many to many relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "visit")
public class Visit {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "date")
 private Date date;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
 private User user;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
 @JoinTable(
        name = "visit_has_attraction",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "visit_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attraction_id")
 )
 List<Attraction> attractions;
 //Constructer, Getters and Setters
 }
```

JPA Repository

```
public List<Attraction> findAttractionsByVisitList(Visit visit);
```

ER of the app
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SLhx.png)

Comment: Add `@JsonIgnore` on top of any lists that you declared. or try to use `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference`

Comment: Can you retrieve the data from the database? Does the issue only happen later? Maybe when serializing the data to JSON?

Comment: The issue happens when i retrieve data from table with the many to many relationship

Comment: If i add @JsonIgnore i won't be able to retrieve data on thses lists right.

Comment: Can you please add your solution as the answer? Maybe some other user may be interested

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I am sorry i didn't notice your comment ill add the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I added @JsonIgnore to one of the sides in many to many relationships and added @JsonBackReference to ManyToOne side and @JsonManagedReference to OneToMany side of all the one to many relationships.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attraction")
public class Attraction {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 @Column(name = "historical")
 private Boolean historical;

 @Column(name = "religious")
 private Boolean religious;

 @Column(name = "beaches")
 private Boolean beaches;

 @Column(name = "animal_sanc")
 private Boolean animalSanc;

 @Column(name = "hiking")
 private Boolean hiking;

 @Column(name = "forest")
 private Boolean forest;

 @Column(name = "parks")
 private Boolean parks;

 @Column(name = "lakes")
 private Boolean lakes;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "bungalow_id")
 @JsonBackReference
 private Bungalow bungalow;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
 @JoinTable(
        name = "visit_has_attraction",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attraction_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "visit_id")
 )
 @JsonIgnore
 private List<Visit> visitList;
 //Constructer, Getters and Setters
}
```

Visit entity
This is the other end of the many to many relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "visit")
public class Visit {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "date")
 private Date date;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
 @JsonBackReference
 private User user;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
 @JoinTable(
        name = "visit_has_attraction",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "visit_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attraction_id")
 )
 List<Attraction> attractions;
 //Constructer, Getters and Setters
 }
```